# Perl: Check standard output for specific text and perform an action

Tags: linux, perl, dns, ping

I'm attempting to write a tool that checks an IP address for existing PTR records then if there are no PTR records does a ping to see if it response.

Then if there is no response, it should print a message saying

This is what I have so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$ping = "100%";
use warnings;
while (defined($line = <>)) {
    chomp($line);
    print `nslookup $line`;
    if ("NXDOMAIN") {
        print `ping -c 1 -w 2.0 $line`;
        if ($ping) {
            print "IP Address '$line' is available.\n"
        }
    }
}
```

What I can't seem to get to work are the if statements for if the text NXDOMAIN is in the output it performs the ping. Then if the text of the ping contains $ping it prints the following line.

```
print "IP Address '$line' is available.\n"
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: you should use one of the [multiple modules already written](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=nslookup&mode=all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the value returned by your commands:

```
# THIS CODE IS UNTESTED, but should get the idea across.
my $nslookupOut = `nslookup $line`;
print $nslookupOut;
if ( $nslookupOut =~ /NXDOMAIN/ ) {
    my $pingOut = `ping -c 1 -w 2.0 $line`;
    print $pingOut;
    if ( $pingOut =~ /$ping/ ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. That's going to go a long way towards me getting good at Perl. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the built in libraries of perl to do what you need.  Here is an example of how to achieve your ping with perl:

```
use Net::Ping;

my @list = ("10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2", "10.0.0.3");

foreach my $addr (@list) {
    my $p = Net::Ping->new();
    print "IP Address '$addr' is not responsive.\n" if !$p->ping ($addr);
    $p->close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$ping` isn't undef. So the `if` condition always returns true!

You need to set the `$ping` variable if you get negative response from that particular `IP`.